# Possibility of Vulgar Latin or Old Romanian origins of "Akoldo" and "Dir" in medieval Primary Chronicles of Kievan Rus

Tags: vocabulary, language-evolution, history, vulgar-latin, romance-languages

The names "Akoldo" (that's how he was called for the first time, and later he is mentioned as Askold) and "Dir" are mentioned as the first Varangian rulers of Kiev in the medieval Primary Chronicles of Kievan Rus. Is there any linguistic evidence to suggest that these names might have resulted from a translation error from either vulgar Latin or early Romanian language in the 10th-12th centuries?

Based on my research, the following meanings might be associated with "Akoldo" in Latin and modern Romance languages:

- welcome
- accept
- dwell near
- assist (in the context of having some troubles with the Khazars)

And for "Dir":

- say/tell
- order/direct

For example, the original fragment "Akoldo and Dir stayed in this city" could be translated as "We welcome you and tell you to stay in this city."

I would like to hear arguments from experts in the field of linguistics that could either support or refute my idea that these names might have resulted from a translation error from either Vulgar Latin or early Romanian language in the 10th-12th centuries.

Comment: "Based on my research". Can you share that research? Also despite asking about Vulgar Latin, this might be better on the Linguistics site instead.

Comment: Some of the Western Romance languages lost the second consonant in *dicere* (hence French *dire*) but the entire Eastern Romance preserved it (as /tʃ/), so even without knowing anything else about the history of the Romance languages the connection of Dir to *dico* is already questionable.